# Does '' bear down on'' mean: bite or take strong measures against?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am learning phrasal verb on https://www.englishpage.com/prepositions/phrasaldictionaryB.html. According to this website,'' bear down on'' means bite or take strong measures against. And I looked it up on Longman and Oxford dictionary, but i couldn't find these meanings. :((

Comment: It means several different things, depending on context.

Comment: That 18 wheeler bearing down on my motorcycle is a threat to life and limb.  Bearing down on the stone in my facet cutter increases both friction and the cutting rate.

Answer (score 1):

From M-W:

***[bear down on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear%20down)***

> 1 : emphasize
>
> 2 : to weigh heavily on : Burden
>
> - *But for all the political pressure bearing down on Hong Kong, the city still has a way of defying the naysayers and standing up — even if that means rising against the tide of history itself.*

The example from your source is:

> The U.S.A. is bearing down on drug traffickers.

which, figuratively, may imply *taking measures against* ....

Answer (score 0):

I might "bear down" on a bicycle tube patch, to make sure it adheres to the tube.

I fighter pilot might "bear down" on his target.

A cop might "bear down" on the speeder he's pursuing.

A prosecuting attorney might "bear down" on an evasive witness in court.

A student might "bear down" (apply maximum effort) while studying a difficult subject.

A sports announcer might say "Bear down on the 30 yard line!"